# Why GC does not collect an unused object

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, c#-6.0

I'm trying to understand how the GC acts when an object is not being used anymore, my test is to do nothing with the object (after used) but it didn't work, the object's destructor was never called.

I've created an example program trying to wait until the object is destroyed, but after 4 hours running nothing happens.

Note: I know if I set the object to null the GC will collect it, but I just want to see the "normal" way the GC itself collects the object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string FilePath = @"C:\objLifeCycle.txt";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = GetList();
            Console.WriteLine("Results received! Object Id: [{0}] time: [{1}]", result.ObjId, DateTime.Now);

            //result = null;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("...");
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            });

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static LinkList GetList()
        {
            return new LinkList(FilePath) { "link1", "link2", "link3" };
        }
    }
}

internal class LinkList : List<string>
{
    internal string ObjId { get; set; }

    internal string FilePath { get; set; }

    internal LinkList(string filePath)
    {
        ObjId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        FilePath = filePath;

        WriteFile($"Object LinkList with Id [{ObjId}] has been created at [{DateTime.Now}]");
    }

    ~LinkList()
    {
        WriteFile($"Object LinkList with Id [{ObjId}] has been destroyed at [{DateTime.Now}]");

        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private void WriteFile(string line)
    {
        var sw = new StreamWriter(FilePath, true);
        sw.WriteLine(line);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: By adding a destructor to your LinkList class the instantiated object is promoted to the gen1 heap instantly. Gen1 heap collections are not performed as often as gen0 heap collections, and as your probably has plenty memory available they will most likely never happen for this application.

Answer (score 3):

GC will not collect free resources in a deterministic Way. The program should need memory to ask for resources. If there are enough resources the GC won't collect anything because there is not necessary. Also the GC could collect memory only in program "Idle" states...

I strongly recommend you to read: [Understanding .NET Garbage Collection](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-net-garbage-collection)

As you can test and see in documentation there is no way to force a garbage collection even calling [`GC.Collect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[image: GC.Collect documentation]

And besides of that actually you need to understand that there are some GC flavors depending on platform and CLR implementations

[Cross-VM Object Collections](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/)

For test purposes you can increase the need of Collect memory using [GC.AddMemoryPressure Method (Int64)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: The program in the question explicitly calls `GC.Collect()`, which collects all generations. So this is not relevant.

Comment: @svick But it is, actually.  Calling GC.Collection undeterministically starts a collection, but in the case shown it's *undeterministic* if the variable in question is actually going to be collected, even when a collection happens.  The GC is *allowed* to conclude that the variable is never used again, and can therefore be cleaned up, but it is not *required* to do so (regardless of whether the code is compiled in release/debug build).

Comment: I have updated my answer with complementary information explaining why GC.Collect doesn't imply a forced  garbage collection

Comment: @Servy I think calling it undeterministic, while technically true, is confusing. On any given implementation with any given settings, it's very likely going to be deterministic. So I think a better way would be to say that it's *implementation-defined* whether it's eligible for GC or not.

Comment: @svick I feel that my second sentence is the clearest way of saying it.  The GC is *allowed* to collect the object, but it is not *required* to do so.  Depending on that to happen would be wrong.

Comment: @Servy I compiled in release mode and it works as expected, now my second test is removing the explicit call to GC.Collect (and compile in release mode), it has been working for a couple hours and nothing happens...

Comment: @JorgeRamírez That's what I'd expect to see.  When the program is doing nothing and there are no objects being created, the GC isn't going to need to run, so it won't.

Comment: @Servy So, How could I "force" the GC to collect without calling it explicitly? creating more objects inside the while loop?

Comment: @JorgeRamírez You don't want to.  It's *correct* that it's not collecting objects when it doesn't need to collect objects.  It's doing its job.  Let it.

Comment: @Servy the test is for educational purposes, so Yes, I want to force it to collect.

Comment: @JorgeRamírez have you used  `GC.AddMemoryPressure` as I suggest you in my answer?

Answer (score 3):

The GC *will* collect the object, but only in Release mode.

In Debug mode, the variable `result` will exist as long as it's in scope, even if you don't use it, so that the debugger can keep showing you its value. But this also means the object can't be garbage collected.

In Release mode, .Net is smart enough to realize the object will not be used anymore, so it will be eligible for garbage collection. And when the GC is invoked (in your case explicitly by calling `GC.Collect()`), it will collect it.

Comment: `The GC will collect the object` That is not a true statement.  It is *allowed* to collect the object, if it wants to, but it is not *required* to do so, even in release mode.  The implementation chooses to do so, but it could just as easily choose not to perform that optimization.