# Trying to understand the Memory Consumption of ConcurrentQueue<T>

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, queue

I have a simple **Producer / Consumer Pattern**, where the producer produces data every **1 ms**. The Consumer consumes the data every **3 ms**. So I need a **Queue** to store the data temporary. Everything fine untill now.

The Queue gets filled with the following code:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<string> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

public void enqueueData(string data)
{
    _queue.Enqueue(data);
}
```

Then I have a Thread, which consumes the data (data must be stored in database - it takes about ~3ms to store one record)

```
private Thread _consumerThread;
```

In the constructor of this class, I start the Thread to consume the data when the first record gets stored. Very simple untill now.

```
public Consumer()
{
    _consumerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(consumeData));
    _consumerThread.Start();
}
```

The following method will consume the data and store it in database:

```
private string _resultData = null;
private object _lock = new object();

private void consumeData()
{
    while(true)
    {
        while(_queue.Count > 0)
        {
            _resultData = null;
            if (_queue.TryDequeue(out _resultData))
            {
                lock(_lock)
                {
                    DataHandler.processData(_resultData); // this does the database stuff
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(_sleeptime); // sleep 50ms 
    }
}
```

**Now I will explain my Problem:**

- When the application starts the memory usage looks the following:

[image]

- After a few seconds of producing data, it looks the following:

[image]

In this few seconds, I produce about ~50.000 records of data which all must be stored in database. The application needs about 1 Minute to finish this Job.

**The Problem ist:** Even when ALL data records are stored in database (means, that `queue.count == 0`), the memory usage of the application did not reduce!

**This application must run 24/7 and store millions of data records. So I will run out of memory after a few minutes / hours. (There is a producing-break after 30 Minutes in which I calculated, that all data should be dequeued, so it will work, if the memory usage will reduce).**

**Why does the memory not reduce after dequeued every single item?**

I tested this application lots of hours and the memory consumption comes from the 
`_queue.Enqueue(data);` line. So I am 100% sure, that no other line of code is responsible for the memory usage.

Even when I use `queue.clear();` or force `GB.collect();` after dequeued all items, the memory usage still looks like:

[image]

**Can someone explain me this memory usage of the Queue or ConcurrentQueue in C#?**

**Why does it not reduce after dequeued all items?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: .NET is a garbage collected environment. Unless your machine is memory constrained (which it isn't) there is no pressing need for the GC to kick in and collect memory. Why is this in issue for you? This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why GC does not collect an unused object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926303/why-gc-does-not-collect-an-unused-object)

Comment: So is my understanding right: The GC of .NET only collects unused items, when I NEED more memory? That means: I have no memory problem, because when more memory is needed, the .NET GC will collect (old) unused items and NOT allocate more memory?

Comment: @mjwills This is an issue, because I think that the memory usage will grow infinitely when not cleaned up the objects (although all items are dequeued). And I try to understand how the dequeued objects will be handled.

Comment: This is how `ConcurrentQueue` works. `Clear()` will not release alreade occupied memory and there is no need to force GC to collect garbage, because there is no garbage. You may recreate a new instance of `ConcurrentQueue`, so old one will be collected by GC.

Comment: Is there any reason to have private string _resultData = null; as a class members an not a local variable you pass on.

 while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                queue.TryDequeue(out var result);
                lock(_lock)
                {
                    DataHandler.processData(result); 
                }
                
            }; 

Wat is the mem usage if you remove the datahandeler line and let the queu only dequeu

Comment: For testing purposes only you can add GC.Collect in your code and see if it affects amount of memory. You can also use external application for this like PerfView https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/releases/tag/P2.0.15 and run PerfView.exe ForceGC [ProcessName | Process ID]   Finally you can take memory dump with Perfview or other tool and see if your objects are referenced or they are garbage waiting to be collected.  FYI, even on 16Gb RAM server you can easily get 5-6 Gb or garbage not yet collected.

Comment: @RazorShorts There is no reason. out var result will not work, but I changed into a local variable. Thanks for that hint. When I remove the datahandler the queue will NOT grow, because it consumes as fast as the producer produces. When I add a delay in that loop, then the memory usage is the same as before.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but personally I prefer to use a `BlockingCollection` for this kind of pattern, no need then for a `Thread.Sleep` then which is not very elegant and potentially costs that bit of time.

Comment: @Toberto i can reproduce your issue only when i fill the queue faster then the handler can handle it and Indefinitely. When i queu with a finite amount i get the following result.

Size at 254143 => 8936836
Size at 231091 => 8202844
Size at 227746 => 8069704
Size at 256880 => 9041052
Size at 193989 => 6842492
Size at 120459 => 4263580
Size at 51237 => 1861264
Size at 70592 => 2522736
Size at 4928 => 226932
Size at 260351 => 9160192
Size at 194354 => 6856156
Size at 129847 => 4730900
Size at 67004 => 2394132
Size at 12977 => 524236

Comment: `because I think that the memory usage will grow infinitely` That is something you should **test** rather than assume. If it is an issue, let us know. But I suspect it won't be.

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue. Did you figure out what was going on?